# SQL Server 2008 Update inside of case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-update, case

I am trying to create a stored procedure for assigning call in customers to callers. We have several teams of callers that are identified by a variable @team_id. What I want to do is check and see if the customer (@code) has someone assigned to them yet. If they do, return that person's ID. If not, run the THEN statement that determines who it should be assigned to, update the record to that caller, and return that caller's ID. Here is what I have, but it won't let me run the update inside the select. I would like to avoid updating the table every time (adding an update clause to the end of the stored procedure) if I can.

```
declare @team_id char(3), @code char(4)
--If team is an intake department
if (@team_id IN ('03V', '09X'))
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.intake_caller_id IS NOT NULL and a.intake_caller_id <> '' THEN a.intake_caller_id
        ELSE
            (
                SELECT employee_id
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(a.id) as count, a.employee_id
                    FROM event.dbo.event a
                    JOIN event.dbo.event_triage b ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
                    WHERE task_id in ('WS', 'WF', 'WT', 'WU' ) and a.status = 1 AND b.team_id = @team_id
                    GROUP BY a.employee_id
                    ORDER BY count ASC
                ) a
                update event.dbo.referral_data
                SET intake_caller_id = a.employee_id
                WHERE CODE_ = @code
            )
        END
    FROM  event.dbo.referral_data a 
    WHERE CODE_ = @code
ELSE 
--if team is a PO department
IF (@team_id IN ('00R', '154'))
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN @team_id = '00R' AND intake_rx_caller_id IS NOT NULL AND intake_rx_caller_id <> '' THEN intake_rx_caller_id
            WHEN @team_id = '00R' AND (intake_rx_caller_id IS NULL OR intake_rx_caller_id = '') THEN 
                (
                    SELECT employee_id
                    FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT top 1 COUNT(a.id) as count, a.employee_id
                        FROM event.dbo.event a 
                        JOIN event.dbo.event_triage b ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
                        WHERE task_id IN ('WR', 'CR') AND status = 1 and b.team_id = '00R'
                        GROUP BY a.employee_id
                        ORDER BY count ASC
                    ) a
                )
            WHEN @team_id = '154' AND reorder_rx_caller_id IS NOT NULL AND reorder_rx_caller_id <> '' THEN reorder_rx_caller_id
            WHEN @team_id = '154' AND (reorder_rx_caller_id IS NULL OR reorder_rx_caller_id = '') THEN
                (
                    SELECT employee_id
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT top 1 COUNT(a.id) as count, a.employee_id
                        FROM event.dbo.event a 
                        JOIN event.dbo.event_triage b ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
                        WHERE task_id IN ('RS', 'RY') AND status = 1 and b.team_id = '154'
                        GROUP BY a.employee_id
                        ORDER BY count ASC
                    )a
                )
            END
    FROM event.dbo.doctor_data 
    WHERE CODE_ = @code
```

Comment: UPDATE isn't working because it is inside SELECT. It should be after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you update first and then do a select inside first IF statement.
You can apply the same conditional logic in update statement.

**Edit**:here is the code.Not tested though....

```
DECLARE @team_id CHAR(3)
, @code CHAR(4) 
 IF ( @team_id IN ( '03V' , '09X' ) ) 
  BEGIN

        ;WITH  CTE
                AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                                COUNT(a.id) AS count
                              , a.employee_id
                     FROM       event.dbo.event a
                                JOIN event.dbo.event_triage b
                                      ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
                     WHERE      task_id IN ( 'WS' , 'WF' , 'WT' , 'WU' )
                                AND a.status = 1
                                AND b.team_id = @team_id
                     GROUP BY   a.employee_id
                     ORDER BY   count ASC
                   )
              UPDATE      a
              SET         intake_caller_id = ( SELECT employee_id FROM CTE)
              FROM        event.dbo.referral_data AS a
              WHERE       CODE_ = @code
                          AND ISNULL(a.intake_caller_id,'')=''                                     

        SELECT      a.intake_caller_id
        FROM        event.dbo.referral_data a
        WHERE       CODE_ = @code
  END
ELSE  
  IF ( @team_id IN ( '00R' , '154' ) ) 
        BEGIN
              SELECT      CASE WHEN @team_id = '00R'
                                    AND intake_rx_caller_id IS NOT NULL
                                    AND intake_rx_caller_id <> '' THEN intake_rx_caller_id
                               WHEN @team_id = '00R'
                                    AND ( intake_rx_caller_id IS NULL
                                          OR intake_rx_caller_id = ''
                                        ) THEN ( SELECT employee_id
                                                 FROM   ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                                    COUNT(a.id) AS count
                                                                  , a.employee_id
                                                          FROM      event.dbo.event a
                                                                    JOIN event.dbo.event_triage b
                                                                          ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
                                                          WHERE     task_id IN ( 'WR' , 'CR' )
                                                                    AND status = 1
                                                                    AND b.team_id = '00R'
                                                          GROUP BY  a.employee_id
                                                          ORDER BY  count ASC
                                                        ) a
                                               )
                               WHEN @team_id = '154'
                                    AND reorder_rx_caller_id IS NOT NULL
                                    AND reorder_rx_caller_id <> '' THEN reorder_rx_caller_id
                               WHEN @team_id = '154'
                                    AND ( reorder_rx_caller_id IS NULL
                                          OR reorder_rx_caller_id = ''
                                        ) THEN ( SELECT employee_id
                                                 FROM   ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                                    COUNT(a.id) AS count
                                                                  , a.employee_id
                                                          FROM      event.dbo.event a
                                                                    JOIN event.dbo.event_triage b
                                                                          ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
                                                          WHERE     task_id IN ( 'RS' , 'RY' )
                                                                    AND status = 1
                                                                    AND b.team_id = '154'
                                                          GROUP BY  a.employee_id
                                                          ORDER BY  count ASC
                                                        ) a
                                               )
                          END
              FROM        event.dbo.doctor_data
              WHERE       CODE_ = @code 
        END
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your advice and made the update statement first (if it needed to be updated) and then did a simple select afterwards.